# Reader app - use WebView or Canvas?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-canvas

I'm writing one of those reader applications. I would like to know if you have opinions and arguments for and against using `WebView` and `Canvas` (with `drawText()`) to achieve it.

What are the requirements:

- **format text according to a few html tags: `<p>`, `<strong>`, `<h3>`, `<br/>`, `<a>`,**
- **display images within the text (they are in `<img>` tags),**
- display the text in two columns on tablet devices,
- paging the text (Google currents style)

The ones in bold are absolutely required. The latter are strongly desired, but I can drop them.

---

So as far as my knowledge goes:

**`WebView`** will be great when it comes to displaying the html formatted text. I also don't have to take care of loading images, tey will be loaded automatically with `<img>` tags (will they, even if I use `loadData()` instead of `loadUrl()`?). The problems begin if I try to page the text. **Is there a possibility to count the size of the text in a `WebView`** and reflow it into multiple pages (using `ViewPager`)?

**`Canvas`** is great when it comes to counting the size of the text, putting it into columns and pages. But I will have to handle all the HTML tags myself, format the text myself. What is even worse, I will have to extract images' urls, handle the downloading and putting them back to the text (reflowing the whole text every time they load). **Am I right?**

---

Can you point some other advantages and disadvantages of using them? Which would you choose? Or maybe something else? Or is there some lib which does at least some of the work for me?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Textview combined with spanned text and viewpagers for the paging.

Comment: I think it would be problematic when it comes to two things:
1. displaying images - find img tags, break the text there and finish the `TextView`, then put `ImageView`, then start another `TextView`?
2. Counting the size of the displayed text to know where to end one page and when to start another is more problematic with `TextView` than `Canvas` isn't it?

Comment: Textviews can contain images. Spanned text can contain images and the textview will show them. Paging is a problem no matter wich control you use. Maybe you can work with the max line property of the textview but the problem will be the images. I don't know if images take lines or something like that.

Comment: That's interesting, But will the `TextView` display and `<img>` tag just like that, without any async downloading etc? I'll check it, but maybe you know it immediately. `drawText()` is nice when it comes to counting the size of the text as far as I read.

Comment: Yea you will have to download those images Async. Thats a problem with the spanned text. But imo the rendering is faster then when using a webview. So its worth it.